# Is there any way to split a PDF file based on the number of characters?

Tags: python, pdf

I would like to split a PDF file based on the number of characters.
Is it possible to find the number of characters in a PDF file using Python?
I searched, but I could not find it.

Comment: PDFs don't really flow linearly... can you provide more information about what you want to do?

Comment: You should instead look up how to get the *text* of a PDF via Python, because then you can count the number of characters in it.

Comment: @Chris:For example,I would like to split 100000 characters PDF file into 10000 characters PDF file each.

Comment: @RandomDavis:Did you mean it is difficult to split a PDF file like a txt file?

Comment: @Sapphire no I meant that that'd be the easiest way to get the number of characters for each page, so you can figure out which pages you need to split on. Splitting a PDF by pages seems like it'd be trivial with any PDF library, but I'm not sure about splitting on an exact character count - but that's only because I'm not super familiar with working with PDFs in that way.